# Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to query local Cassandra tables using Apache-Spark, however I'm running into this error when running any select show statement

> Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$

**Versions:**

- Cassandra:version 3.11.2 | cqlsh version 5.0.1
- Apache-Spark: version 2.3.1
- Scala version 2.12.6

Cassandra Keyspace -> Table

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test_users
...   WITH REPLICATION = { 
...    'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 
...    'replication_factor' : 1 
...   };

CREATE TABLE member (
    member_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    member_name varchar,
    member_age int
);


cqlsh> select * from member;

+---------+----------+-----------------+
|member_id|member_age|      member_name|
+---------+----------+-----------------+
|        5|        53|     Walter White|
|        6|        29|Henry Derplestick|
|        1|        67|      Larry David|
|        4|        31|       Joe Schmoe|
|        2|        19|  Karen Dinglebop|
|        3|        49|     Kenny Logins|
+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

**QueryMembers.Scala**

```
spark-shell  --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.0-M3 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host="10.0.0.233" 

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import org.joda.time.LocalDate
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{litrow_number}
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val conf = new SparkConf(true).
  set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "10.0.0.233").
  set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")

val sc = new SparkContext("spark://10.0.0.233:9042", "test", conf)

val members = spark.
        read.
        format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").
        options(Map( "table" -> "member", "keyspace" -> "test_users" )).
        load()

members.printSchema()

val older_members = members.select("member_id", "member_age", "member_name").
  where("member_age > 50")
older_members: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [member_id: bigint, member_age: int ... 1 more field]

older_members.show() // breaks here
```

Errors

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "member_id", "member_age", "member_name" FROM "test_users"."member" WHERE token("member_id") > ? AND token("member_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$

```
2018-07-29 18:57:09 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 29)
java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "member_id", "member_age", "member_name" FROM "test_users"."member" WHERE token("member_id") > ? AND token("member_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:293)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:307)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:50)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:46)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.converterToCassandra(ColumnType.scala:229)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$13.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:282)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$13.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:282)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Spark 2.3.0 you need to use the latest version of spark-cassandra-connector: 2.3.1...

Also, you must not use version 2.0.0-M3 - it's the pre-release version. Latest version in the 2.0.x series is 2.0.9.  You need always check the versions at [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector).

Answer (score 0):

After researching further I decided to try rolling back the Apache Spark version from 2.3.1 to 2.2.0, which has resolved the issue.

I'm now able to run and get the results of the query

```
val older_members = members.select("member_id", "member_age", "member_name").
 where("member_age > 50")

 older_members.show
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with this connector. spent almost 1 day to figure out. Dont use spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-2.0.0-M3, Use newer version of spark-cassandra-connector.

Thanks @Alex Ott